# Using SFML in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, linker-errors, sfml

I'm trying to make use of SFML in Code::Blocks. I've followed the guide at https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-cb.php to the letter but it doesn't work. Please help!

In the project's build options I have specified everything:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Errors:

[image]

Here is simple code:

```
int main(){

#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Epic RPG");

return 0;
}
```

The errors seem to indicate that linking went wrong - I don't see how

Comment: You probably should have copied and pasted the errors as text instead of taking a picture of text.

Comment: Errors such as: D:\sfml-release\_Sources\SFML\src\SFML\Graphics\ImageLoader.cpp|280|undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress'|

Comment: Looks like you are missing a link to a jpeg library and opengl.

Comment: You have missed some of the dependencies that are listed on the very guide you linked to, so obviously you did not follow it to the letter. Namely `opengl32 winmm freetype`

Comment: [Please don't post your code/exceptions as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Answer (score 0):

I used CB's own SFML project type and it works now

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using static libs, if you want to use them you need to reference SFML source code as well. Instead, try to put the other same libraries but without the "-s" on them.